# How to translate webpage language using Selenium ChromeDriver

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

When I run the scripts, webpage opened in Turkey language. I want to convert in English language,tried below piece of code using chrome options but it is setting browser language to English not webpage language.please help

```
static DesiredCapabilities setChromeCapabilities()
   {
      Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();

      prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 1);
      prefs.put("download.default_directory", "C:\\dev\\tmpReport");

      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
      options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
      options.addArguments("chrome.switches","--disable-extensions");
      options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
      options.addArguments("--lang=en");  **//tried adding this line of code** 

      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
      capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY,options);
      return capabilities;
   }
```